# how to generate fixtures for postgresql schema and tables using django

Tags: django, postgresql-9.0

I am using django and postgresql db to develop my project, the db has 3 schemas. And I am writing raw quires using connection string to fetch data and insert data into tables.

Example:

```
from django.db import connection 
    query = "select * from schema1.records" 
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    output = cursor.fetchall()
```

Like way I am using in my all views.

I wanted to write test cases to my views, so i need to generate fixtures to test my views, how to I generate fixtures for schemas and tables. Please help.

Note: I did not write any models i just used raw queries in my whole project.

Comment: As a sidenote, schema support is actively being worked on: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6148

Comment: are you getting my question, if not please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
manage.py dumpdata help
```

This will show how to use loaddata to generate fixtures.

Comment: loaddata can insert the data into dabase if i had json file right.

Comment: but i don't have the models for my tables, because i am using existed database and tables.

Comment: I think you forgot "-" before help : 

manage.py dumpdata -help